# How to nest if statement in a while loop in python 3

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, rsa

I am having trouble with the below code

```
try:
    while True:
        # Get next line from file
        line = fileHandler.readline()
        plaintext = pow(int(line), a, n)    # a, n and line read from file are integers.
        if len(str(plaintext)) % 2 != 0:
            plaintext = '0{}'.format(plaintext)  # adding zero if odd no of digits
            i = 0
            while i < len(plaintext) - 1:
                print(plaintext)
                row = int(plaintext[i])
                col = int(plaintext[i + 1])
                decrypted.append(matrix[row][col])
                if row > 0:
                    row -= 1
                print(matrix[row][col - 1])
                i = i + 2

        print(plaintext)
        if not line:
            print(decrypted)
            break
except ValueError:
    pass
```

When len(plaintext) % 2 != 0 fails the code in the while loop below it fails to execute. I know I have the while loop inside the if loop so it happens. But when I move the while loop out of if, nothing is executed. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

I get the following output now :

> 19475276822512119441620228045431117884359382536936226816
>   05297161768145254779131968343762551184670149997720486635
>
> H
>
> 05297161768145254779131968343762551184670149997720486635
>
> p
>
> 05297161768145254779131968343762551184670149997720486635
>
> &

The operations for the first line is not executed but they are performed when if

```
len(str(plaintext)) % 2 != 0:
            plaintext = '0{}'.format(plaintext)
```

this condition is true.

I hope I am clear. Thank you!

Comment: Well, have you tried printing out `str(plaintext)` to see if the length is actually even or odd?

Comment: I have. I'm reading line by line so it is odd for a few lines and even for others.

Comment: Okay, then the if statement runs, or it doesn't... I'm not sure I understand the question. Maybe you could add an else statement to make it more clear?

Comment: @Lafexlos how would that make a difference. It still enters the loop right?

Comment: The if statement does run. But when %2 ==0 further operations are not performed. Yes I will add it. But did you understand now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When len(plaintext) % 2 != 0 fails the code in the while loop below it fails to execute

Yes, that's how if statements work

> when I move the while loop out of if, nothing is execute

It's not clear how far outside you moved it, but it still needs to be within the outer while loop, and you can use a range rather than another while loop

```
while True:
    ... 
    plaintext = str(pow(int(line), a, n)) 
    if len(plaintext) % 2 != 0:
        plaintext = '0{}'.format(plaintext)  # adding zero if odd no of digits
    # indent if you only want to execute this for odd length numbers 
    for i in range(0, len(plaintext), 2):
        print(plaintext)
        # ...
```

Comment: For this it throws me an error saying
    for i in range(0, len(plaintext), 2):
   TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: Edited to fix it

Comment: that worked! I never would have thought about that. Thanks!